# Use custom fields in registration email for Wordpress Cimy

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I was wondering if there’s a way to get custom fields and display them in the registration email? I've been trying for awhile and can't figure it out.

I notice there's a strrep for the USERNAME and PASSWORD strings, but I am not sure how to access the custom variables that I have created so I can do some other strreps for my other variables.

Thanks for your time!

Finn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it via redefining `wp_new_user_notification()` function:

```
if ( !function_exists('wp_new_user_notification') ) :
    function wp_new_user_notification( $user_id, $deprecated = null, $notify = '' ) {
        // apply your changes
}
endif;
```

And in the function you can get custom fields using `$user_id`.

**Note:** It will not work in theme `functions.php`. You should create a plug-in and do place your code there, since plug-in files loaded before `pluggable.php` file, where located the original function. Also check `if ( !function_exists('wp_new_user_notification') )` to avoid PHP errors in case it has been redefined in another plug-in.

These links might be helpful:
[The original function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_new_user_notification/),
[Wordpress pluggable functions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pluggable_Functions),
[Example](http://www.webtipblog.com/change-wordpress-user-registration-welcome-email/).